# Show toast message or dialogue Using FutureBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-futurebuilder

I want when user sends wrong data to the server then futureBuilder shows a dialogue or toast message above all other widgets to the user without removing all other widgets because FutureBuilder only return one widget !!

### what I did I showed a pop up then I returned the same screen again is it good approach of implementing it

---

My FutureBuilder Code

---

```
FutureBuilder<dynamic> buildFutureBuilder() {
    return FutureBuilder<dynamic>(
        future: _futureCreatedUser,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot);
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            // If we got an error
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(
                  '${snapshot.error} occurred',
                  style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.black),
                ),
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
              if (registerViewModelInstance?.requestSuccess == true) {
                return const HomePage();
              }

              if (registerViewModelInstance?.dataError == true) {
                Future(() {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text('Erro!'),
                            content: const Text(
                                'Required Fields is missing or Email was taken'),
                            actions: <Widget>[
                              TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () =>
                                      Navigator.of(context).pop('Ok'),
                                  child: const Text('Ok'))
                            ],
                          ));
                });
                return RegisterView(); //<= the same screen 
              }
            }
          }
         
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        });
  }
```

Comment: If you just want to show users the dialog box if they enter the wrong input then why don't you handle that part during data submission itself, like error text that appears below input or Show Red Text below the submit button when they try to submit wrong data as this will be good in terms of UX instead of using FutureBuilder to check whether data is invalid or not. This will make sure that there won't be any invalid data in the database or from wherever you are fetching data

Comment: @ItsHarsh.json there is no problem with your answer I just wanted to know how to use future builder with this kind of implementation

Comment: the showDialog method is wrapped inside a Future, which means that it will not be executed immediately but will be scheduled to run later. This can cause issues because the code will continue to execute before the dialog is actually shown, and the build method will return the RegisterView widget before the dialog is shown. This means that the user might not see the dialog at all.

Comment: @DewaPrabawa I'm already on RegisterView and I want to show the dialogue in the same RegisterView that's why I'm returning RegisterView then the dialogue above RegisterView 

but there is a way to show the dialogue directly above the RegisterView without needing to return the registerView first